# Error while migrating from Magento 1.9 CE to Magento 2.1 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool

Integrity check failed error after Stores Step. Can any one help me how to resolve this, below is my migration command.

```
   user@comp:/var/www/html/magece21$ sudo php -f bin/magento migrate:settings vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.0.1/config.xml
settingsnamee
[2016-11-01 06:35:11][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
[2016-11-01 06:35:11][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec


  [Migration\Exception]   
  Integrity Check failed
```

Comment: Can try with this https://github.com/ubertheme/module-ubdatamigration?

Comment: I tried `ubdatamigration tool`, it's giving error in Sales step.

Comment: Same Error or Different?

Comment: No,  that's different error.

Comment: Update that as well in question. Using above github i'm getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error in Sales step Mahendra mentioned, may I know which migration tool version you're using? 
At the moment, we have [UB Data Migration Lite](http://bit.ly/UB-data-migration-lite) and [UB Data Migration Pro](http://bit.ly/ub-data-migration-v3) version.

Please note that our [old free script on Github](https://github.com/ubertheme) is no longer maintained, and replaced with the newer versions mentioned above.

Regards,
Ubertheme team

Comment: On Step 6,  Mage2CustomerAddreeEntityText: Value cannot be blank and on Step 7, Page is not working. I used Uber migration tool 0.1.25.

Comment: Hi Mahendra Jella,

Comment: Please discard our previous comment (it was entered by mistake). 

Somehow we missed your reply. As you did not maintain the old script on Github that you mentioned. 
Please consider to move forward with our newer release V3 with an overhaul of codebase to improve performance, while it was enhanced with delta migration, command-line interface, PHP memcache support etc., 

You can check out [https://youtu.be/R4UBLe2kf-I](this tutorial video) to learn more on our UB Data Migration V3. 

Hope that helps.

An Nguyen
On behalf of Ubertheme team

Comment: *Update: You can check out the tutorial video via: https://youtu.be/R4UBLe2kf-I